# Serverless: Deprecation warning: Variables resolver reports following resolution errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

[edited]

After attempting to deploy my app to AWS I get these errors from the Serverless framework

### Environment Information ---------------------------

 Operating System:          Windows 64
 
Node Version:              12.22.6(14.17.3 also as I am using NVM)

 Framework Version:         2.60.0

 Plugin Version:            5.4.4

 SDK Version:               4.3.0

 Components Version:        3.17.1

Steps to reproduce the error

1. install serverless globally `npm i -g serverless`
2. deploy the app to AWS `serverless deploy --verbose --aws-account default`

In short, these are the remaining errors:

- Tracing disabled (for almost all lambda functions)
- CLI options definitions were upgraded with "type" ...
- some node modules audits
- Cloudformation is in DELETE_FAILED state and can not be updated

console

```sh
Serverless Warning --------------------------------------
  CLI options definitions were upgraded with "type" property (which could be one of "string", "boolean", "multiple"). Below listed plugins do not predefine type for introduced options:  
   - ServerlessWebpack for "out"
  Please report this issue in plugin issue tracker.
Serverless: Using configuration:
{
  "webpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
  "includeModules": false,
  "packager": "npm",
  "packagerOptions": {}
}
Serverless: Removing C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\contrib\serverless_todo_app\backend\.webpack
Serverless: Bundling with Webpack...
(node:9148) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ERRORS] DeprecationWarning: Module.errors was removed (use getErrors instead)
asset src/lambda/http/getTodo.js 4.6 MiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/http/getTodo) 2 related assets
asset src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl.js 4.42 MiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl) 2 related assets
asset src/lambda/http/updateTodo.js 4.42 MiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/http/updateTodo) 2 related assets
asset src/lambda/http/deleteTodo.js 4.42 MiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/http/deleteTodo) 2 related assets
asset src/lambda/http/createTodo.js 4.42 MiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/http/createTodo) 2 related assets
asset src/lambda/http/getTodos.js 4.42 MiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/http/getTodos) 2 related assets
asset src/lambda/auth/auth0Authorizer.js 296 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: src/lambda/auth/auth0Authorizer) 1 related asset
runtime modules 5.68 KiB 29 modules
orphan modules 5.96 KiB [orphan] 6 modules
javascript modules 3.21 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 3.17 MiB
    cacheable modules 3.17 MiB 848 modules
    6 modules
  modules by path ./src/lambda/ 38.4 KiB 7 modules
json modules 3.14 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/aws-sdk/apis/*.json 3.12 MiB 403 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/ 12.8 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/ajv/lib/ 3.11 KiB
    ./node_modules/ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-07.json 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]  
    ./node_modules/ajv/lib/refs/data.json 407 bytes [built] [code generated]
  4 modules
WARNING in ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/patchers/call_capturer.js 41:32-47
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/segments/attributes/aws.js 1:19-61
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/aws-xray.js 77:19-71 86:22-77
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/index.js 2:0-38
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk/lib/index.js 2:14-42
 @ ./src/helpers/attachmentUtils.ts 2:0-40 3:13-31
 @ ./src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl.ts 4:0-61 11:22-34
WARNING in ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js 127:29-43      
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/node_modules/colors/safe.js 8:13-36
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/config.js 9:13-35       
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/node_modules/winston/lib/winston.js 29:25-52
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/logger.js 1:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/aws-xray.js 2:14-33
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/lib/index.js 2:0-38
 @ ./node_modules/aws-xray-sdk/lib/index.js 2:14-42
 @ ./src/helpers/attachmentUtils.ts 2:0-40 3:13-31
 @ ./src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl.ts 4:0-61 11:22-34
2 warnings have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
webpack compiled with 2 warnings in 114413 ms
Serverless: Zip service: C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\contrib\serverless_todo_app\backend\.webpack\service [6555 ms]
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Remove C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\contrib\serverless_todo_app\backend\.webpack
Serverless: Installing dependencies for custom CloudFormation resources...
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-Auth"
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-GetTodos"
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-GetTodo"
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-CreateTodo"
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-UpdateTodo"
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-DeleteTodo"
Serverless: Tracing DISABLED for function "serverless-todo-app-dev-GenerateUploadUrl"        
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service serverless-todo-app.zip file to S3 (13.55 MB)...
Serverless: Uploading custom CloudFormation resources...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Publishing service to the Serverless Dashboard...
Serverless: Successfully published your service to the Serverless Dashboard: https://app.serverless.com/oussamabouchikhi/apps/serverless-todo-app/serverless-todo-app/dev/us-east-1       
 
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
  Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:515681156515:stack/serverless-todo-app-dev/6fc5b880-2128-11ec-b839-0e6d2682b977 is in DELETE_FAILED state and can not be updated.
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              12.22.6
     Framework Version:         2.60.0
     Plugin Version:            5.4.4
     SDK Version:               4.3.0
     Components Version:        3.17.1
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Starting with next major version, "http.request.schema" property will be replaced by "http.request.schemas".
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#AWS_API_GATEWAY_SCHEMAS
```

serverless.yaml

```yaml
org: oussamabouchikhi
app: serverless-todo-app
service: serverless-todo-app

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-plugin-tracing

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221'

  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}

  tracing:
    lambda: true
    apiGateway: true

  # Use these variables in the functions and resouorces section below. For example,
  # ${self:provider.environment.ATTACHMENT_S3_BUCKET}
  environment:
    TODOS_TABLE: Todos-${self:provider.stage}
    TODOS_CREATED_AT_INDEX: CreatedAtIndex
    ATTACHMENTS_S3_BUCKET: serverless-c4-todo-images-${self:provider.stage}
    SIGNED_URL_EXPIRATION: 300

  logs:
    # Enable API Gateway logs
    restApi: true

  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
            - xray:PutTraceSegments
          Resource: '*'

functions:
  Auth:
    handler: src/lambda/auth/auth0Authorizer.handler

  # Provide iamRoleStatements property for performing Actions on DynamoDB
  GetTodos:
    handler: src/lambda/http/getTodos.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: todos
          cors: true
          authorizer: Auth
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:GetObject
        Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.ATTACHMENTS_S3_BUCKET}/*
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

  GetTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/getTodo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: todos/{todoId}
          cors: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

  # Provide iamRoleStatements property. Decide the Actions and AWS Resource.
  # To refer to an AWS resource defined in the "Resources" section, you can use "Resource: !GetAtt <resource-name>.Arn"
  # To validate incoming HTTP requests, we have provided the request schemas in function definition below.
  CreateTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/createTodo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: todos
          cors: true
          authorizer: Auth
          request:
            schemas:
              application/json: ${file(models/create-todo-model.json)}
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

  # Provide property for setting up CORS, Authorizer, iamRoleStatements, and request schemas
  UpdateTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/updateTodo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: patch
          path: todos/{todoId}
          cors: true
          authorizer: Auth
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(models/update-todo-model.json)}
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

  # Provide property for setting up CORS, Authorizer, iamRoleStatements
  DeleteTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/deleteTodo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: delete
          path: todos/{todoId}
          cors: true
          authorizer: Auth
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:DeleteItem
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

  # Provide property for setting up CORS, Authorizer, iamRoleStatements
  GenerateUploadUrl:
    handler: src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: todos/{todoId}/attachment
          cors: true
          authorizer: Auth
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:PutObject
          - s3:GetObject
        Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.ATTACHMENTS_S3_BUCKET}/*
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

resources:
  Resources:
    # Add necessary AWS resources. You will need at least the following AWS resources
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi

    # Create a DynamoDB table with local secondary index and a composite key
    TodosTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: todoId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: todoId
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

    AttachmentsBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:provider.environment.ATTACHMENTS_S3_BUCKET}
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedOrigins:
                - '*'
              AllowedHeaders:
                - '*'
              AllowedMethods:
                - GET
                - PUT
                - POST
                - DELETE
                - HEAD
              MaxAge: 3000

    # Complete the policy below and attach it to the bucket defined above
    # For cross referencing the name of the bucket, use "!Ref AttachmentsBucket"
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: MyPolicy
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Action: 's3:GetObject'
              Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.ATTACHMENTS_S3_BUCKET}/*'
        Bucket: !Ref AttachmentsBucket
```

Comment: I see at least one typo: `ATTACHEMENTS_S3_BUCKET` should be `ATTACHMENTS_S3_BUCKET`.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoE for noticing that, I fixed the typos and other errors showed up. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

In your API Gateway Response resource declared as CloudFormation, you've mis-indented the `ResponseType` attribute. It should be inside the `Properties` block.

The error is:
`The CloudFormation template is invalid: Invalid template resource property 'ResponseType'`, which tipped me off.

This should work:

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    # Add necessary AWS resources. You will need at least the following AWS resources
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse
      Properties:
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
      RestApiId:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
```

You can review the rest of the documentation for this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-gatewayresponse.html)

Comment: I edited it and still getting unrecognized!

Comment: Is the error message the same? Please update your post with the new error. If my suggestion solves your original error, please consider accepting it and opening a new issue if you have a new question.

Comment: After I added `ResponseParameters` property as shown 
[here](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/)  it' now working

Answer (score 0):

Actual error is:

```
<yourLambdaARN> is in DELETE_FAILED state and can not be updated.
```

This means you tried to delete your lambda function or the entire application and it failed at some point, maybe you had a non-empty bucket or something like that, you can check this in the console, under the CloudFormation section search for DELETE_FAILED event for this lambda and it will tell you what's wrong.

Serverless won't deploy if application is in this state, so you have no option but to find what made it fail. Once you solve it you'll be able to redeploy.